# Android INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE INCOMPATIBLE?

Tags: android

I had to reinstall my OS. Now I'm getting this error as I try to run my app, asking me if I want to uninstall my apk and lose my data (No I do not).

```
INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE INCOMPATIBLE
```

What is it that needs to be compatible? It's the same app. Same code. Does the SDK version need to match up? Build version? It's possible one of those has been updated since Android Studio had to be reinstalled.

I've generated the signed APK, but that doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you are trying to "upgrade" to a smaller versionCode, as specified in your AndroidManifest.